# Low power and singular fit in mixed model despite high number of observations and low number of factors

Tags: lme4, mixed-models

Despite I made 276 independent observations across 5 sites (lowest number of obs per site: 23), I get the singularity warning and low power to fit a model with **one** categorical factor (two levels) and one random factor (site). Anybody could tell why would that happen?

Here is a reproducible example:

dataset:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/azpnhnemgyo0i72/example.xlsx?dl=0

```
require(readxl)
require(lme4)

df <- data.frame((read_excel("Example.xlsx", sheet=1)))
    
m1 = lmer(ds.lac ~ sand.avail + (1|site), data = df)

summary(m1)

simr::powerSim(m1, nsim=100)

# results in:
# fit: see ?isSingular
# boundary (singular) fit: sSimulating: 
# |============================Simulating: 
# |============================Simulating: 
# |============================
Power for predictor 'sand.avail', 9.00%  (95% confidence interval): ( 4.20, 16.40)

# Test: Kenward Roger (package pbkrtest)
```

Comment: Hi @Agus camacho! I think you can improve your post including some data (`dput()`) and also informing in which part of the process are you having the waning: fitting or simulating the model. I suggest you move your question to stackexchange (It is more about stats than code). Singular models may appear for different reasons, commonly due to lack of variation in some variables: a description of variables may give you the answer. The response variable in the model seems to have many zeros: that can be the source of the warning and may also indicate the need of use for another model

Comment: doesn't `sand.avail` have 3 rather than 2 levels?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Jose, this really belongs on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com).

```r
pd <- position_dodge(width=0.75)
gg1 <- ggplot(df,
       aes(x = site, y = ds.lac, colour = sand.avail)) +
    stat_sum(position = pd, alpha = 0.8)
ggsave("powerSim.png")
```

Also as suggested by Jose, there are a number of reasons this data set doesn't have as much information as you would like

- most (75%) of the observations are 0 (`mean(df$ds.lac==0)` counts the proportion)
- you only have all three `sand.avail` types available at one site, two of the sites only have one type available (thus there will be a lot of overlap between the random effect of site and the effect of `sand.avail`)
- for modern mixed models, 5 levels of the grouping variable is generally considered a *minimum*

Furthermore, I have a concern about what `powerSim` is doing here; this seems to be a *post hoc* power analysis (i.e., estimating the power of a data set you have already gathered), which is widely criticized by statisticians. It would be perfectly reasonable to say "why isn't the effect of `sand.avail` significant for this model, fitted to these data?" (e.g. `car::Anova(m1)` gives p=0.66), but asking about the *power* for this data set is conceptually problematic.

[image]

Comment: Dear @Ben Bolker, thank you very much for your advice. I really thought I was in crossvalidated when I made the question, maybe I inadvertently got out of it when I had to log in to make the question. Is ther a way how to move questions from stack overflow to cross validatedçThe warning came during fitting. I think I understand the issue after your explanation. however, why a minimum number of five for

Comment: If a couple more sufficiently high-rep users vote to close & migrate, it will go automatically (slightly easier than deleting and reposting, as I would have to repost my answer ...)  "How many levels is enough" is discussed in Gelman and Hill 2007 *Applied Regression Modeling* (it should be in the GLMM FAQ as well, but might not be); also see https://peerj.com/articles/1114/